# Backbone Marionette - Updating view object based on incoming data

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette, publish-subscribe, updatemodel

I have an application which updates based on live incoming iq packets to a pubsub node.

At the moment I am using backbone marionette to create the intial view when I receive a respnose from my request. This creates an object using the template, which I then need to feed the live data into.

I want to use backbone marionette to update this object with the live data but I'm unsure how it would be done.

Currently, when I receive the correct type of iq to the pubsub node I am getting out the info I want, then calling a function "updatewell" which updates the object created by backbone from the original response.

Is backbone able to update this object from the pubsub event? How would I call it?

Edit below shows approximately what I do in the updatewell function. Can backbone marionette handle all of this? It's not as simple as "replace the template with new data", I need to hide/show information based on what is returned.

The main issue I have using backbone marionette is that it constantly creates new objects. In the updatewell code you notice that I am defining divs with an ID that is unique, and updating based on that id (which is returned in the IQ to the pubsub). This means the correct object is always updated, something I can't find to define in backbone marionette.

**In essence, I need to tell marionette: "These are a new set of values, does a model with this value as it's id exist? if not, create it, if it does, update it with the other values"**

Please ask for more information.

My code is below (simplified as of 1st May 2014):

Backbone Marionette code:

```
InfoWell = Backbone.Model.extend({});

InfoWells = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model : InfoWell
});

InfoWellView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template : "#template-infowell",
    tagName : 'div',
    className : 'alert alert-custom',

initialize: function () {
    this.$el.prop("id", this.model.get("datetime"));
},
});

InfoWellsView = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    tagName : "div",
    id : "info-well-list",
    template : "#template-infowells",
    itemView : InfoWellView,

});

MainJs.addInitializer(function(options) {
    var aInfoWellsView = new InfoWellsView({
        collection : options.InfoWells
    });
    MainJs.InfoWellsContainer.show(aInfoWellsView);
});

var InfoWells = new InfoWells();
```

Response code to create well:

```
    InfoWells.add(new InfoWell({
        id : datetime,
        datetime : datetime,
        title : title,
        body : body,
        comments : comments
    }));
```

Pubsub code:

```
pubsubHandlerInfo = function(iq) {
    var date = $(iq).find('datetime').get()
    ...     
    MainJs.vent.trigger("updatewell", {
        datetime : datetime,
        title : title,
        body : body,
        comments : comments
    });
    return true;
}
```

EDIT
Updatewell function:

```
MainJs.vent.bind("updatewell", function(data) {
        var datetime = data.datetime;

        if (datetime.length) {
            $("#hidden-state").trigger('testactions');
            $('#hidden-state').bind('testactions', updateWell(data))
        }

        function updateWell(data) {

        $("#body-" + data.datetime).html(data.body);
        $("#comments-" + data.datetime).html(data.comments);

        if (data.title === "something1") {
            $("#"+data.datetime+"-Something1").unbind('click').click(something1Action)
        } else if (data.title === "something2") {
            $("#"+data.datetime+"-Something2").unbind('click').click(something2Action)
        }

        function something1Action() {MainJs.function1();}
        function something2Action() {MainJs.function2();}
    });
```

So in words, what I'm trying to do is this:
Replace **MainJs.vent.trigger("updatewell", {** with **InfoWells.add(new InfoWell({** to send a new model to backbone. Backbone will see this model and check if there already exists a model with the ID of the datetime value.

As a first step, if there is a model with this ID, *I need to update two divs in the model (the body and the comment) with the new values sent*. If there is no model with this ID, I need to create one as normal (which works at the moment).

As a second step, I would need to check the value of the title and create a click function for the title div.

Big thank you for any help you can provide.

EDIT:
As mentioned by Dmytro, I can use set and get, but I'm not sure how this applies here. Where do i tell it to get the existing ID and how do I set new values to it? Any link to documentation regarding this would be brilliant please.

SOLUTION:
So, understand get and set and where to apply it is the main part of updating backbone models.

Below is the code I've added to my pubsub handler which does it correctly.

```
    var update = InfoWells.get(datetime);
    console.log(update);
    if (update !== undefined && update !== null){
        update.set({
title : title,
body : body,
comments : comments
        });
    };
```

So for those who want to know what I'm doing. I create a variable called update which gets it's value from looking at the collection (*InfoWells*) and getting the ID with value *datetime*, which from above you can see is the unique ID value I assigned every model.

I then check if this update value actually exists, and if it does I call the ***set*** command, which tells it to send these new values into the model for the attributes mentioned. Note that I left out *id* as I will never update that for a model.

Then, as Dmytro mentioned, I added the render to the ItemView when a model changes.

```
    modelEvents: {
        "change": "render"
    }
```

The next step for me, to replicate my update well, is use ***"change:ATTRIBUTE" : function()***.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all `Backbone.Model` should represent current state of your data and than view should render it to HTML. Updating HTML directly it is not Marionette way.

If you want to don't create new model but update exited when receive data about existed one you can just find existed model in collection(using, `get` or `find` or `findWhere`) and update it with new attributes using `set`.

Than `change` events will be triggered in your model if some attributes changed. You can listen to this event and rerender your view using `modelEvents`:

```
InfoWellView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template : "#template-infowell",
    tagName : 'div',
    className : 'alert alert-custom',
    modelEvents: {
      'change': 'render'
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Dmytro, Sorry but I'm not sure how to get the existing model to update... you mention using get, find or findWhere but I don't know what I'm trying to find. How do I tell it to find "this specific model". Do I use my custom ID for the model? Or does backbone create one? Thanks!

Comment: By default backbone model's id is `id` attribute. But you can specify any attribute as id using `idAttribute` http://backbonejs.org/#Model-idAttribute. And you can find existing model by id using `get as: `var existedWell = wells.get(124);`

Comment: Hi Dmytro, sorry for the late response was moved to another project, but finally back here. Been looking through this for just over a week now and I'm unable to find out how to tell marionette: **"These are a bunch of new values, check if a model with this ID exists (ID is the datetime) and if it does, update the values, if not, create it"**. From my understanding, this is what marionette does and what you mentioned above confirms that (I shouldn't update HTML directly). I've updated my code to massively simplify what I actually need to do. Thanks again.

Comment: Took a while, but I got it! Updated main with answer

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need to add an item to collection, compositeView will automatically render this item ([wiki](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.compositeview.md#model-and-collection-rendering)).

Set handler to "updatewell" event like [here](http://jsbin.com/nerun/2/edit?js).

Comment: Hi 4ega, Unfortunately this causes the same issue I had before where it constantly creates new objects with the updated information. To give more information (will add to original post) the function 'updatewell' adds a number of new functions into the mix based on the returned information, it's not as simple as "Replace this text with the new text". Personally, I don't feel backbone marionette can handle this but reading the documentation it seems it should be able to.